# WPF Toolkit AutoCompleteBox Programmatically Set Caret Position

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, wpftoolkit, toolkit, autocompletebox

I want to programmatically focus on an **AutoCompleteBox** and set its caret position just like a **TextBox**. We can do this on a TextBox with the **Select(int, int)** method but AutoCompleteBox doesn't have this. Can we extend AutoCompleteBox to achieve this? I'm using C#. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either extend the `AutoCompleteBox` class or simply get the `TextBox` directly in your code and call the `Select` method.

The `TextBox` in the default template of `AutoCompleteBox` is named "Text", so you can either call `yourAutoCompleteBox.Template.FindName("Text", yourAutoCompleteBox)` to get the `TextBox`, or create a derived class like this:

```
public class AutoCompleteBoxEx : AutoCompleteBox
{
    private TextBox _textBox;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        if (Template == null) return;
        _textBox = Template.FindName("Text", this) as TextBox;
    }

    public void Select(int start, int length)
    {
        if (_textBox == null) return;
        _textBox.Select(start, length);
    }
}
```